# Why mvcaction4 code snippet does not react?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

When I write `mvcaction4` and press `tab` 2 times it doesn't work. Currently I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Comment: Do you mean you want Visual Studio to insert a snippet? If so, you need to press `Tab` after the keyword...

Comment: I do so, but it doesn't work. By the way Resharper is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC4 snippets are supported in VS2017. MVC 4 is an optional component that's part of the web workload. If you don't have it installed and try to open an MVC 4 project it should prompt you to add the missing component to Visual Studio.

Support for MVC 4 is limited. We don't allow you to create new MVC 4 projects, but you can
 - Open existing MVC 4 projects
 - Scaffold controllers/views
 - Use snippets

**EDIT** MVC4 snippets will only show up for an MVC 4 project. The snippets are tied to the .csproj/.vbproj ProjectTypeGuid properties.

Below is a screenshot from MVC4 snippets in VS2017

[image]

Comment: Okay, so do you suggest from VS2017 we must create our own mvcaction4/5/6 snippets ourselves? Will such snippets be available for VS2017 at all?

Answer (score 11):

I think the `mvcaction4` and `mvcpostaction4` snippets has been removed from Visual Studio 2017.

All you can do is to import these snippets from Visual Studio 2015.  Here is the steps you can do:

1. Assume you have already installed both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017.
2. Open Visual Studio 2017, then click menu [Tools] -> [Code Snippets Manager]
3. Switch Language to `CSharp` in the **Code Snippets Manager** window
4. Hit the `Import` button
5. Enter `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Visual Studio 2015\Snippets\VC#\1033\ASP.NET MVC 4` and select all items ( `mvcaction.snippet` and `mvcpostaction.snippet` )
6. Hit **Finish** button to complete import.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem so I followed Will Huang's answer but created my own snippet. I will leave the code snippet below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets >
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>mvcaction</Title>
            <Shortcut>mvcaction</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for an MVC Action</Description>
            <Author>Jordan Gregory-Wallis</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>name</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Action Name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>Action</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public ActionResult $name$()
    {
        return View();
    }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is to check that the snippet you want to use exists. Open the "Code Snippets Manager" (either Tools Menu or search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>).

Ensure that the snippet you want to use is listed. Assuming it is...

Disable all your extensions (Resharper, everything). If it fixes the problem, turn extensions back on one at a time until you've identified the problem.

If snippets don't work after disabling all extensions, leave them disabled for now and check your Visual Studio key bindings `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> and search for keyboard. Search for `Edit.InvokeSnippetFromShortcut`. Ensure that it's set to <kbd>Tab</kbd> (you may also want to check/set `Edit.InsertSnippet`).

Re-enable your extensions and check it all still works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to search bar ---> type MVC4 ---> you get the option to download the support for MVC --->download and install and then the snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this code snippet in **Visual Studio 2022**,
*Tools -> Code Snippets Manager -> Import -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc4\Snippets\VC#\1033

mvcaction.snippet* and *mvcpostaction.snippet*